# Android. How to bring up WiFi

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have an embedded module running Android and the OS disconnects WiFi after about 5 mins of inactivity. If I then run any application that uses network connectivity, the WiFi remains off and the icon does not show in the status bar. I have to go into settings and WiFi settings to get the WiFi to come back up.

I have an application that has to send data periodically over the WiFi connection. If I start the programme with the WiFi active and send data every 2-3 mins the WiFi remains active and never disconnects. If I let the WiFi disconnect and then try to send, it never comes back up. In code, the call to:

```
    wifi.isWifiEnabled()
```

always returns true but the icon remains hidden meaning that the WiFi is not connected. I have tried to call reconnect() from the code as a test with a button, but the WiFi never comes up.

From the terminal debug port I can type IFCONFIG WLAN0 UP and the WiFi connects to the AP.

Is there any call I can make that will cause the WiFi to reconnect and is there any way I can actually detect that the WiFi is disconnected other than detecting that the TCP/IP connection failed?

IN RESPONSE TO A REQUEST BELOW, I HAVE ADDED THE FOLLOWING CODE SNIPPETS AND LOGCAT OUTPUT

```
    wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    wifiLock = wifi.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "Mini210-Lock");
    if(!wifiLock.isHeld())
    {
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        wifi.reconnect();
        // wifi.reassociate(); // Also try this!!
        wifiLock.acquire();    // Keep system alive
        Log.i("Alarm System", "WiFi Lock Acquired");
    }
```

Logcat shows the following when the above code is run.

```
    09-10 22:43:25.273: I/Alarm System(611): WiFi Lock Acquired
    09-10 22:43:25.417: I/ActivityManager(91): Display axon.alarm.system/.AlarmSystemActivity: +15s198ms (total +4h23m59s645ms)
    09-10 22:43:31.636: W/wpa_supplicant(133): Failed to initiate AP scan.
    09-10 22:43:41.636: W/wpa_supplicant(133): Failed to initiate AP scan.
```

When I enter ifconfig wlan0 up in the debug monitor port, the following appears in logcat (some duplicate output has been deleted)

```
    09-10 22:56:12.726: I/wpa_supplicant(133): CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS  Ready
    09-10 22:56:12.726: I/wpa_supplicant(133): Trying to associate with 00:22:75:32:a9:47 (SSID='kpk_mobile' freq=2412 MHz)
    09-10 22:56:20.976: D/dhcpcd(623): checking 192.168.1.123 is available on attached networks
    09-10 22:56:20.976: D/dhcpcd(623): sending ARP probe (1 of 3), next in 1.73 seconds
    09-10 22:56:22.710: D/dhcpcd(623): sending ARP probe (2 of 3), next in 1.00 seconds
    09-10 22:56:23.714: D/dhcpcd(623): sending ARP probe (3 of 3), next in 2.00 seconds
    09-10 22:56:25.718: D/dhcpcd(623): leased 192.168.1.123 for 86400 seconds
    09-10 22:56:25.718: D/dhcpcd(623): adding IP address 192.168.1.123/24
    09-10 22:56:25.718: D/dhcpcd(623): adding route to 0.0.0.0/0 via 192.168.1.1
    09-10 22:56:25.730: D/dhcpcd(623): executing `/system/etc/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks', reason BOUND
    09-10 22:56:25.773: D/dhcpcd(623): forking to background
    09-10 22:56:25.804: V/WifiStateTracker(91): DhcpHandler: DHCP request succeeded
    09-10 22:56:25.804: V/WifiStateTracker(91): IP configuration: ipaddr 192.168.1.123  gateway 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 dns1 192.168.1.1 dns2 0.0.0.0 DHCP server 192.168.1.1 lease 86400 seconds
    09-10 22:56:25.816: I/TelephonyRegistry(91): notifyDataConnection: state=0 isDataConnectivityPossible=false reason=dataDisabled interfaceName=null networkType=0
    09-10 22:56:25.828: D/WifiWatchdogService(91): (android.server.ServerThread) kpk_mobile (00:22:75:32:a9:47) does not require the watchdog
    09-10 22:56:25.843: V/FTPDroid(356): EventsReceiver: NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION (exists: true, connected: true)
    09-10 22:56:25.863: D/Tethering(91): MasterInitialState.processMessage what=3
    09-10 22:56:25.902: I/GTalkService(278): [ServiceAutoStarter] --- connectivity changed
    09-10 22:56:25.902: I/GTalkService(278): [ServiceAutoStarter] --- start GTalk   service ---
    09-10 22:56:27.789: D/dhcpcd(647): sending ARP announce (1 of 2), next in 2.00 seconds
    09-10 22:56:29.789: D/dhcpcd(647): sending ARP announce (2 of 2)
    09-10 22:56:29.789: D/dhcpcd(647): renew in 43196 seconds
```

Comment: 1) What's the module? and what do you think of it so far? 2) does the module come with any special APIs for specific board features? or is it pure android SDK stuff?

Comment: Hi Juian. I am using a Mini210 from FriendlyArm. It comes with Android 2.3 source and I have built it to include RS232, GPIO and I2C capability using native code JNI so I can access them from within Android code. I have found it to work well except for the WiFi issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

Try this, don't know if working.

Answer (score 0):

Use this permissions in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Set its state to ON using below:

```
wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I have all of those in my code and manifest and it still won't come up.

Comment: I have edited the above original posting to show what you asked for. Sorry, I am new to the forum so just learning the ropes on how to post here!!